# jQuery bind file input dynamically and retrieve file in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function will create a fileinput field for example

```
function addCol () {
   //add file input fields

   //last line of the function will bind all file input fields to a function
   $('#upload_'+rowNum[1]+'_'+colSize).bind('change', {fh:'upload_'+rowNum[1]+'_'+colSize}, readURL);
}
```

The function

```
function readURL(e) {
    alert(e.data.fh);
    var input = $('#'+e.data.fh);
    alert(input.files);
}
```

As a result,

```
e.data.fh = 'upload_1_1'
input.files = undefined
```

Anyone know how I can retrieve the file from the file input fields dynamically?

Comment: @Zamboney it works, you can make your comments as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `e.target.files[0]` the `e.target` return the html tag `<input type="file">` and in this tag there is a property call `files` that contain all of the files that been loaded